# Entity select Dropdown

Tags: entities, views

I'm working on a Drupal 8 view that is going to be a page.

How can I make an exposed entity filter a dropdown? The entity is not a content type, but rather a custom entity with it's own module.

I can't seem to find any documentation about it.

Answer (score 0):

Views on Drupal 8 are slightly different, but you might consider [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/162060) (given for [Exposed filters with dropdown selections](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40080/views-exposed-filters-with-dropdown-selections)), which gives you a quick module way of creating a custom node-based exposed filter drop down for a Drupal 7 view. This is essentially what I would suggest for your use case.